# Add constructor to AspectJ aspect with parameters

Tags: java, aspectj

I have

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

int x,y,z;
public MyAspect(int _x,int _y,int _z){
    x=_x;
    y=_y;
    z=_z;
}



@After("execution(public * save(..))")
public void methodAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    //code
}
```

after calling save method,it doesn't execute the methodAfter. However,without constructor,it works.How can I use aspectj with constructors?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working in a spring environment, so what I suggest you'll do is:

1. Add @Component annotation to your aspect.
2. Use @Inject and @Value annotations to inject it with the required values for x,y,z.